# Pentaho unable to get value date from result zero date value prohibited

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

still trying to learn pentaho and i tried my query which works fine in my pgAdmin4 and Aqua Data Studio and DBeaver.
But weirdly , when I "copy-paste" the select query to the table input step, and i do preview by right-clicking and preview.
It gave me an error in the Execution Results : Logging

```
Pentaho unable to get value date from result zero date value prohibited
```

I have a data that has null value , what should i do then ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the query is working in pgAdmin4, DBeaver, etc because they aren't executing the query for the whole table, but from some first rows that don't have the null value, while Pentaho produces an error when executing the query over the whole rows in the table.
Seems like an query error more than an Pentaho error, try to look how the data for null values is retrieved in pgAdmin4, and apply the COALESCE function if needed.